# How to use same randomly generated value in header.php and footer.php in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, random, dynamically-generated

I want to use same randomly generated value in header.php and footer.php in wordpress. i have try this function to randomly generated value:

```
function randValue() {
$randCheaters = substr(md5(microtime()),rand(0,26),5);
return $randCheaters;
}
```

In header.php i use some thing like this

```
<header id="<? echo randValue(); ?>">
```

and in footer.php i have used this

```
<footer id="<? echo randValue(); ?>">
```

The problem is it generate different value in footer and header, how can i get the same value in both place.

Comment: call the function just once, store the returned value, echo that twice

Comment: Hey @Dagon can u give me a example how can i do that.

Comment: a *professional developer* lol should be able to work that out :)

Comment: @Dagon very good catch, and so true ;-)

Answer (score 0):

How about rather than generating the random number *each* time through a function call, you do it *once* at the start of your page, then store it in a variable which you later call.

```
//No function, code runs automatically
$randCheaters = substr(md5(microtime()),rand(0,26),5);  //Variable $randCheaters now contains a random value
```

Now echo `$randomCheaters` into both ids, and they will be the same

```
<header id="<? echo $randCheaters; ?>">
<footer id="<? echo $randCheaters; ?>">
```

Comment: could still use original function

Comment: But this is another way, and more concise. Always more than one way to do something :) @Dagon

Comment: Oh, could you give me the link to your site so I could have a look, if you're not on localhost?

Comment: i am in localhost @joe_young

Comment: Oh, it seems to be working for me. Does the header id work, i.e. it is just the footer which is missing an id?

Comment: Well that's very confusing as it is working for me on my localhost. Could you give us the code you are using?

Comment: Had u put $randCheaters = substr(md5(microtime()),rand(0,26),5); in header.php ?

Comment: Nope, I put it before the html document, i.e. before the `<!doctype html>`

Comment: I also put it before <!doctype html> but didn't work. is your <!doctype html> is inside header.php ?

Comment: Nope, they're all in the same file

Answer (score 0):

You have to define the variable before echoing in any place. From your question it seems that the random code should be placed in header. As you know header section may comes just after html tag. So its better you assign the variable before html tag.

`<?php 
 $randCheaters = substr(md5(microtime()),rand(0,26),5);
?>
<html>`

We dont need function to be called. Now echo in `id=` attribute under header and footer.

If you want to use it for every page then assign the rand value to a session variable.

```
`$_SESSION['randCheaters']=$randCheaters;`
```

Then use this session variable by just echoing.

Posting from mobile phone. Editing option is limited. Sorry for wrong alignments.

Comment: But in wordpress theme <html> is inside header.php and if i use $randCheaters = substr(md5(microtime()),rand(0,26),5); in header.php it will not work in footer.php. So it need functions.php to generate the value....

Comment: You may try the workarounds. You have got the concept.